# Hi need a formula when i type a value in COL C it looks up that value in COL E,F,G and then displays the value with the appropriate color

Tags: google-spreadsheets

```
enter code here
```

[Hi need a formula when i type a value in COL C it looks up that value in COL E,F,G and then displays the value with the appropriate color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAKUv.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read the tags **before** posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].